# How do I build an Arm version of Docker File for Qnap Arm based Server

Tags: docker, arm, qnap

I have a *Docker* File for my application and I use *Docker Hub* to build it.
This works fine on a *Synology DS218+ Disk Station*, which is Intel based.

*Qnap* supports Docker on both *Intel* and *Arm* devices with its *Container Station* software , I have purchased a TS131P to test this out but it failed with `exec format error`. Apparently I have to build an Arm version of the image, but how do I do this ?

Can I build the image on the Qnap itself somehow ?

**Update**

So my base image was `openjdk:8-jre-alpine`, so I have found on DockerHub an arm32 equivalent of this, https://hub.docker.com/r/arm32v6/openjdk/ so now:

- Created a new BitBucket rep
- Copied over Docker File
- Changed first line of Docker File to `FROM arm32v6/openjdk:8-jre-alpine`
- Created a new *Automated Build* on Docker linked to this repo

But the build is now failing on the second line

```
RUN apk --no-cache add \
       curl \
       tini
```

with

```
[91mstandard_init_linux.go:190: exec user process caused "exec format error"
```

Since I am using arm image I assume that apk should be compiled for arm, or do I need to tell Docker Hub to build on Arm rather than Intel ?

Comment: I think you will have to change the base image of your `Dockerfile`. [Docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/) has images for arm. When playing with a raspberry pi I had used images from [resin.io](https://hub.docker.com/u/resin/)

Comment: okay I have found an arm32 equivalent of by base image, modified first line to FROM arm32v6/openjdk:8-jre-alpine and trying rebuild in dockerhub

Comment: Trouble is after the FROM command I have a RUN cmd (RUN apk --no-cache add curl tini) and on build within DockerHub this is failing with "exec format error". Could it be that although the FROM image is Arm based Docker is trying to build image using Intel and therefore apk comand does'nt work, do I have to tag the architecture in some way.

Comment: I don't understand the *"build within DockerHub"* part. Maybe it's something I haven't used. Have you tried to ssh into your device and try to use `docker build ...` inside Qnap?

Comment: ok, I just saw the update...

Comment: @tgogos i nearly have working, can you see what im missing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52777216/in-docker-hub-is-it-possible-to-build-an-automated-build-for-an-arm-image

Comment: @tgogos Right have it working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is you have to build an arm image on an arm server, so I built in on the Arm nas itself, since this supports Docker, this is what I did

- Ensure ContainerStation running on nas server
- ssh nas server (from PC)
- docker build *buildfile* docker login
- --enter username *username*
- --enter password *password*
- docker images (to get imageId of built image)
- docker tag *imageId* *repoName/imageName*:latest
- docker push

and this was enough to make arm32 version available to be installed on arm32 machine.

Currently I have two separate images, one for Intel and one for Arm. I understand that there is a way to combine multiple images into a single super image, but I have not attempted that yet.
   *repoName/imageName*:latest