# In Docker Hub Is it possible to build an automated build for an Arm Image

Tags: docker, arm, dockerhub

In Docker Hub website Is it possible to build an automated build for an Arm Image ?

I have modified my existing DockerFile to use an Arm base image, but it fails on the next line when it tries to run the `apk` command with `exec format error`. So it looks like Docker Hub is trying to build as Intel despite base image being built for Arm.

Is it possible to build Arm image with Docker Hub website or not ?

If not can anyone provide succint instructions on how to build Arm Image from my Dockerfile either by

- Using my (Intel PC) from the docker command line
- Using my (Intel Mac) from the docker command line
- Using QNAP TS131P Container station, (since this is natively Arm maybe this is simpler)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be relatively easy using the QNAP, alot simpler than it seemed from the posts I had read, I think my confusion was these posts were about building *Arm* version on an *Intel* machine, which i didnt need to do. And all the Arm specific instructions were for Raspberry Pi which had its own problems.

- Created new empty repository in DockerHub
- Uploaded my DockerFile to my webserver
- ssh *qnapserver*
- docker build *DockerFileUrl*
- docker login *DockerHubUsername* *DockerHubPassword*
- docker images (to get imageId of built image)
- docker tag *imageId* *DockerHubNameSpace*/*DockerHubRepository*:latest
- docker push *DockerHubNameSpace*/*DockerHubRepository*:latest

The push worked, and I was then able to use *ContainerStation* to get the image from Docker Hub and run in a container.